# how to handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException at controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Facing the below exception when file upload size exceeds.I want to show user friendly exception when uploaded file size exceeds.But its not hitting the controller to handle the exception.

Exception:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 20 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (2536) exceeds the configured maximum (20).
```

Comment: you've got your exception handlers set up, and they are working elsewhere ? what is the stacktrace of error then

Comment: @NimChimpsky , pls see the above edited post.

Comment: In resolveException method, what are you passing as modelAndView?

Comment: Looks like your HandlerExceptionResolver is not being invoked - String message in resolveException is not reflected anywhere in stacktrace.

Comment: @Prasad, finally got it, it went to ExceptionHandler class, but other issue is when i upload file which exceeds the file limited size(4MB) , i don't want to upload it, i want to display the error message to the client, but as its default behaviour its trying to upload the file may be in cache which i'am noticing now and taking lot of time probably more than 5mins to come back to index page and display error message to the user.Once done i will post the complete example. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your exception stacktrace shows that the request is hitting the dispatcherservlet and consequently the controller - then you simply have your `@exceptiohandler` methods setup incorrectly ([section 16.11.2 @ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)).

Otherwise, if the stacktrace shows the exception is thrown before then ... what is it ?

Comment: as mentioned above its not hitting the controller and stack trace is "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 20 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (2536) exceeds the configured maximum (20)." Please see the above edited post.

Comment: post the stacktrace of error, to me it looks like it is hitting controller and apache commons is throwing error which you are not catching, thus returning a 500

Comment: pls see above post for stack trace, and its not hitting the controller, i kept debug point at controller and checked its not hitting.

Comment: it gets bound to a multipartresolver by sprign before hittig the method body, but it would still throw a controller exception, stacktrace need soemthign liek this http://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKgq.png